# How to get MS Teams private channel's SharePoint site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am following this article [Manage lifecycle of private channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/private-channels-life-cycle-management#using-graph-api-1) to get private channel's site url using App-Only authentication. Its giving the desired result in one tenant for both the requests `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<group_id>/channels?$filter=membershipType eq 'private'
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<group_id>/channels?$filter=membershipType eq 'private'`mentioned in the article but in other tenant its throwing error "502 Bad Gateway" for second request`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<group_id>/channels/<channel_id>/filesFolder` but first one succeeds.
Can anyone suggest what could be the issue? Please note, in both the tenants app has same permissions.

Error:
`{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadGateway",
    "message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "6ab8032b-8d33-4543-b2f1-0e13978e9699",
      "date": "2020-02-05T07:00:11"
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the private channel?
If you are creating the private channel using Graph it will fail until you actually open the channel i Teams.

I found that when you create a team and a private channel in Graph then the private channels drive and SharePoint site is never generated until you actually manually visit the private channel. Once you open the channel in the Teams app this triggers the drive and sharepoint site creation for that private channel. After this is done you can run the line again and it will work. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams//channels//filesFolder

I found no way around this, tried everything from creating channel using PowerShell and so on.

Comment: No, Private channel was created manually and even it has some files.

Comment: and now the same error is there in both the tenants. Can we rely on this particular api?

Comment: Hi Jimmy. Did you find a way to get the Sharepoint Site provisioned automatically without having to open the Private Channel from Teams to trigger the SP Site creation?